# Numeration a numeral with 2 variables

Tags: arithmetic

could you help me ?

If $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that

$(\overline{ab})^{3}=\overline{1c8ab}$

then the value of $2b-a-c$ is ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the overline represent?

Comment: $\overline{ab} $ a numeral of 2 digits in basi 10

Comment: Perhaps, saying that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are decimal digits is more correct (or at least, more precise) than $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can start by noting that the cubic number on the right-hand side has five digits and starts with 1; by inspection $22\le\overline{ab}\le27$. By inspecting *these*, we find that only 24 has a cube with the 8 in the hundreds place: $24^3=13824$. Hence $a=2,b=4,c=3$ and $2b-a-c=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $a, b, c$ are actually *digits* (rather than any arbitrary natural number), we can proceed as follows:

The last digit of any natural number $n$ matches the last digit of $n^3$ unless that last digit is one of $2, 3, 7, 8$.  The fact that the cube has five digits, the first of which is $1$, indicates that $a$ must be $2$, since $20^3 = 8000$ and $30^3 = 27000$.  That leaves the possibilities $20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 29$, which can be checked manually.

Answer (score 0):

This solution hopes to minimize cubing and cube squaring:

Let's call $n=\overline{ab}$.

Note that $n^3-n$ ends with two zeros.

That is, $100$ divides $(n-1)n(n+1)$. Then, since there can't be two multiples of $5$ among three consecutive numbers, one of this three numbers is a multiple of $25$

Since $10000<n^3<20000$ we have $20<10\sqrt[3]{10}\le n\le 10\sqrt[3]{20}<30$. Therefore, $n$ is $24$, $25$ or $26$. But $25\cdot26\cdot 27$ is not a multiple of $100$, so $n$ is $24$ or $25$. Since every power of $5$ greater than $25$ ends with $125$ or $625$, it must be $n=24$.

Sadly we *must* cube $24$ to verify that the hundreds digit of $24^3$ is $8$ and to obtain $c$.

Comment: Sorry  but how $10000<n^3<20000$ ?

Comment: Note that $n^3$ has five digits and begins with $1$.